# Help Config websvn Ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2, svn

I'm newbie in Linux and I want to create a server `websvn` for my programs.
I did install websvn in the server and work but showed me this message.

```
Please set up a repository in include/config.php using $config->parentPath or $config->addRepository. See the installation guide for more details.
```

So I did a nano include/config.php

```
<?php
$config->addRepository("my repos", "file:///var/lib/svn");
$config->setEnscriptPath("/usr/bin");
$config->setSedPath("/bin");
$config->useEnscript();
?>
```

Then a `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Then I go the browser and go to the URL and the page is blank with only this letter `ES`
also in the URL of my browser show this `http://192.168.x.xxx/websvn/listing.php?repname=my+repos`

Here is the route where I have my repos `/var/lib/svn` and inside of that I have to folder `programas` and `pruebas`

Dunno if I did something wrong or not. Will appreciate any help. Grettings

Comment: Hello  MoteCL, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message?

Comment: @abu_bua  Ok thanks, ok my error is if I add the repo in the file config.php I should see the two folder inside the route `/var/lib/svn/` with the view of websvn but the page go blank